# Margin defined in the resource file to be 'included' has no impact

Tags: android

I am trying to re-use the XML defined for a button in a calculator app but the margin value defined within the Button's XML has no effect after it is included in a layout file.

Button's XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Button
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:text="@string/standard_sqrt"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/dark_button_selector"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
```

Button seems to be handling margin pretty well on its own:

[image: Button Layout]

Now, I am simply including it in a TablowRow like this:

```
<TableRow
     android:layout_weight="2"
     android:gravity="center">
     <include layout="@layout/button_component" />
     <include layout="@layout/button_component" />
     <include layout="@layout/button_component" />
     <include layout="@layout/button_component" />
 </TableRow>
```

No matter what value I assign the margin/height/width of the Button, they act the same when included in the table row (i.e without any spaces between them).

[image: Included buttons]

Comment: have u tried to change `android:layout_weight="4"`?

Comment: Yes. It is having no effect.

Comment: can u share your wholelayout with quetsion

Comment: In your layout i wold strongly encouraging you to just put the buttons directly, you gain nothing by using include since is just one button. Anyways if you want to fill the row then you need to change the wrap_content to match parent this way the buttons will fill the parent minus margins. Also do not use dp for text size use sp instead.

Comment: Hi, basically I need to add around 40-50 buttons with exactly the same layout, hence used <include>, it isn't just one button.
Also, as I mentioned in the question, changing the height and width to match_parent has no effect.

Comment: Then you need to add the margin to the include tag.

Comment: It would mean repetition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please put your `Button` inside a parent layout with the margin params :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <RelativeLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_margin="5dp">
     <Button
        .......
        .......
        .......
                />
  </RelativeLayout>
```

And then include it in your `RelativeLayout`